# Custom exceptions- String Comparison

Tags: java, exception

I have a string array with some names. We take an input using a buffer or scanner and compare the input from the user with the string array and display the corresponding details. How would I do this?

Comment: what language ? more details please

Comment: Please always tag your question with the name of the language. Equally you might want to read a [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist); you seem to be missing many of the elements that would make this question answerable. [Your code for instance?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Could you please post it along with any error messages etc?

Answer (score 0):

I think this way you want

```
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class compareName {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String name[]=new String []{"john","pi","ki"};
        System.out.println("Enter name");
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String input=sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(input);
if(input.equals("john"))
{
    System.out.println("I am john");
}
if(input.equals("pi"))
{
    System.out.println("I am pi");
}
if(input.equals("ki"))
{
    System.out.println("I am ki");
}
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually the array has a lot of values. So not possible to check all the values individually. so i wanted to try the use of loops to access all the values and compare them